# WP Query: If field X is empty, show posts based on field Y

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, query

Sorry for the bad title, had difficulties phrasing this questioon in a TLDR fashion.

I have a custom post type for events on my website. Some events only happen in one day, whilst other events might last several days. I want the website to hide events that has passed. This I've done so far by basing it off event_startdate. But I want to adjust my query to basically do this: "If event_enddate is empty, show events where event_startdate has not passed. If event_enddate has a value, show events where event_enddate has not passed".

My current query which works fine based only on the startdate:

```
    
  $query->set( 'meta_key', 'event_startdate' );
  $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
  $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
  $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
              array(
                    'key' => 'event_startdate',
                    'type' => 'DATE',
                    'value' => date("Y.m.d"),
                    'compare' => '>='
                )
            )
        );
});
```

In "oldschool PHP" this would not be a problem for me, but I'm fairly new to Wordpress developing. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you control how the event data is saved? If so I would suggest just saving an end date for single day events.

Comment: Hi @JacobPeattie. I use CPT in combination with ACF.